# You have a 700GB text file on a 1TB drive. You need to remove the first 300k lines from the file. How to solve that?

Tags: linux, file, filesystems, storage

You have a 700GB text file on a 1TB drive. You need to remove the first 300k lines from the file.
Your computer has 16GB of memory and you do not have any other storage.
How do you solve this task? What tools would you use and what are the risks?
Can anyone give me a solution/hints?

Comment: Related: [unix.stackexchange.com/questions/610494](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/610494)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you can use the split command (Linux/Unix).
You'll be able to open a certain amount of lines and edit them.
Then merge them back to the original file.